# how to find duplicate string in an array of strings

Tags: c, string

I have an array of string from which i have to find duplicate string and then remove that duplicate string like i have string

```
 char aa[50]="Amit Hanish Mahesh Amit"
```

Now Amit is duplicate and have to remove it from string .

```
#include "string.h"
main()
{
  char x[100] = "Amit Hanish Mahesh Amit";
  char y[3][100];
  int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0, c = 0, end, t;
  int current = 1;
  while (x[i] != '\0') {
    if (x[i] != ' ') {
      y[k][j] = x[i];
      j++;
      i++;
    } else {
      // c = c + 1;
      i++;
      k++;
      j = 0;
    }
    y[k][j] = '\0';
  }

  for (end = 1; end <= 3; end++) {
    for (t = 0; t < end; t++) {
      if (strcmp(y[end], y[t]) == 0) break;
    }
    if (end == t) {
      strcpy(y[current],y[t]);
       current++;
    }
  }
  y[current] = 0;
  printf("%s",y);
}
```

I have written a smalll routine for it .Does not seems to be worked .Any one have any suggestion where i am going wrong?

Comment: you seem like you didnt use strstr function that makes your task little more efficient try to write a function using strstr thats an advice, I got some work to do when im out of it i will try to create a small function for you Thanks

Comment: He will not learn if you write it for him ;-)

Comment: Your approach is flawed because you don't know in advance the number of word occurence in the initial string. So it is not possible to have y as a fixed array. You take the risk to have a memory fault (which in your case might even be true, as you will have 4 elements instead of 3).

Comment: @Huygens do you have any other idea to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers you got work fine for a small number strings (your example code only has 4).  But, if you're comparing a large number this will be quite slow since you're doing n^2 comparisons.  I'd suggest first splitting the string into an array of strings, then sorting the array using qsort().  In a sorted array all duplicates are guaranteed to be adjacent.  This reduces the time from n^2 to n log n -- the time required to sort.

Comment: I've posted [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764027/how-to-find-duplicate-string-in-an-array-of-strings/7775371#7775371) that uses that approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would split the string array using strtok (see the man page).

So I would have something like this

```
char x[100]="Amit Hanish Mahesh Amit";

/* Preparing the result string */
size_t sz_result = sizeof(char) * (strlen(x) + 1);
char* result = (char*) malloc( sz_result );
result[0] = '\0';

/* Parsing the string from one element to the other */
char* elm = strtok(x, " ");
while( (elm = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL )
{
  ...
```

You will have each element of the string to verify if they are unique.

Then I would use something like a hashmap (you can use the one from the glib) or I would put the read string element in a new string only if it is not already in.

Here is an example for the second solution:

```
  ...
  /* Is the element already in the result string? */
  if ( strstr(result, elm) == NULL )
  {
    /* Then we should add it */
    snprintf( result, sz_result - 1, "%s %s", result, elm );
  }
}
```

In the end if you want x to be modified, you simply copy result in x:

```
strncpy( x, result, 99 );
```

Here is a sample code (not optimised, not using the strn* primitives, etc.)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
  char x[100]="Amit Hanish Mahesh Amit";

  /* Preparing the result string */
  size_t sz_result = sizeof(char) * (strlen(x) + 1);
  char* result = (char*) malloc( sz_result );
  result[0] = '\0';

  /* Parsing the string from one element to the other */
  char* elm = strtok(x, " ");
  if (elm != NULL) strcpy(result, elm);
  while( (elm = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL )
  {
    /* Is the element already in the result string? */
    if ( strstr(result, elm) == NULL )
    {
      /* Then we should add it */
      strcat( result, " " );
      strcat( result, elm );
    }
  }

  strcpy( x, result );

  fprintf( stdout, "Result: %s\n", x );
}
```

Comment: It's way too complicated for doing what you want :-) and I don't have enough time, my apologies.

Comment: With your solution output comes out to be Hanish Mahesh Amit but it should be Amit Hanish Mahesh .Any way @Huygens thanks for your time!!

Comment: This should not be the case. I've made a small test program (quick n'dirty), replaced the snprintf by strcat. And it outputs the result in the order you would like. I'm going to edit my answer to add this sample complete code.

Comment: This answer is not exactly correct. `strstr` is not sensitive to tokens(spaces), and for an input of `Amit  Manish Mahesh Amit Mah` , it strips out the last `Mah` , even though Mah is not the same as Mahesh.

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates from an array without preserving the order of elements:

1. sort the array
2. copy unique elements to the beginning of the array
3. remove the tail with duplicate elements

```
int remove_duplicates(StringArray array) {
  if (! (array and array->items)) return 0; // empty array or NULL

  StringArray_sort(array); // sort

  // unique_copy()
  String result = array->items, last = array->items + array->size;
  for (String first = array->items; first != last; ++result) {
    String_copy(result, first); // copy first to result
    for (String prev = first; ++first != last and String_cmp(prev, first) == 0;)
      { /* skip adjacent equal items */ }
  }
  // shrink
  return StringArray_remove(array, result, last);
}
```

#### Example

```
int main() {
  char text[] = "Mahesh Amit  Hanish Amit";
  StringArray array = split(text, sizeof(text));
  StringArray_dump(array, "<"); // print array before removing duplicates
  if (remove_duplicates(array) < 0)
    perror("error remove_duplicates(), OS error if any");
  StringArray_dump(array, ">"); // print it after
  StringArray_destroy(array);
  return 0;
}
```

Where `split()` is:

```
StringArray split(const char* text, size_t size) {
  if (! (text and text[size-1] == '\0')) return NULL;

  StringArray array = StringArray_create();
  if (! array) return NULL;

  size_t n = -1;
  for (const char* p = text; p != text+size; p += n+1) {
    n = strcspn(p, " \t\n"); // find index of the next whitespace
    if (n == 0) continue; // skip consecutive whitespace

    // append characters in range [p, p+n)
    // as a string to the array
    const String string = String_create(p, n);
    if (StringArray_append(array, string) < 0) {
      String_destroy(string);
      StringArray_destroy(array);
      return NULL;
    }
    String_destroy(string);
   }  
  return array;
}
```

#### Output

```
Mahesh<Amit<Hanish<Amit<
Amit>Hanish>Mahesh>
```

[Full source code](https://gist.github.com/1288918)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that the following line is not intended (assignment, not comparison)

```
 if (end = t) {
```

See what happens, if you code a `==` and come back, if you still have problems.

Hint: Always code blanks around operators, so expressions are easier to read.

Comment: oh its my mistake but still i am not achieve what am looking for

Comment: OK - looked at your code at more detail - 2nd hint: You are using an array of strings `y[3][100]` to store the found words. This array has room for 3 words - but the input line contains 4 words...

Comment: 3rd hint: you're assuming that each word is delimited by one blank - but between the 1st and the 2nd word are 2 blanks - this eats up one entry in array `y`.

Comment: Yes its delimited by one space only thats not my concern

Comment: I'd remove, rethink and then rewrite the whole 2nd part where you're searching the array `y` for duplicates. The loops make no sense this way - and the `strcpy(y[current],y[i]);` goes way behind your array of strings `y` (remember, that you used `i` as index for the string `x`. `y[current] = 0;` makes also no sense (`y[current]` is a string) and the last `printf` lacks a subscript on array `y`.

Comment: I have done some really silly mistakes its strcpy(y[current],y[t])

Answer (score 0):

It's always fun to try to solve this kind of simple problems in C as exercise. Here's my take.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strstrn(const char *haystack, const char *needle, size_t needle_len)
{
    while((haystack = strchr(haystack, *needle)))
    {
        if (strncmp(haystack, needle, needle_len) == 0)
            return (char *) haystack;
        haystack++;
    }
    return NULL;
 }

char* find_duplicate(const char* str, size_t len, size_t dup_len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < (len - dup_len); i++)
    {
        char* r = strstrn(str + i + 1, str + i, dup_len);
        if(r) return r;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s haystack dup_size\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char* haystack = argv[1];
    size_t len = atoi(argv[2]);
    char* r;
    while((r = find_duplicate(haystack, strlen(haystack), len)))
    {
        strcpy(r, r + len);
    }
    puts(haystack);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
 * C Program to Find the Frequency of  Every Word in a 
 * given String
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int count = 0, c = 0, i, j = 0, k, space = 0;
    char str[100], p[50][100], str1[20], ptr1[50][100];
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);
    printf("string length is %d\n", strlen(str));
    for (i = 0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] == ' ')||(str[i] == ', ')||(str[i] == '.'))
        {
            space++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;j < strlen(str);j++)
    {
        if ((str[j] == ' ')||(str[j] == 44)||(str[j] == 46))  
        {    
            p[i][k] = '\0';
            i++;
            k = 0;
        }        
        else
             p[i][k++] = str[j];
    }
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0;i <= space;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j <= space;j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                strcpy(ptr1[k], p[i]);
                k++;
                count++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (strcmp(ptr1[j], p[i]) != 0)
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < count;i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0;j <= space;j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(ptr1[i], p[j]) == 0)
                c++;
        }
        printf("%s -> %d times\n", ptr1[i], c);
        c = 0;
    }
}
```